# Request data over https dosn't work after starting "npm start" and webapp at localhost

Tags: node.js

After execution of "npm install" and "npm start" I receive a errormessage when I start my wepapp at localhost. I use Powershell on Windows 10 to execute the commands.

Here the output after "npm install":

```
C:\Users\Antonio\Documents\GitHub\IoTWebAPP\IoTWebDemo [master ≡ +1 ~1 -0 !]> npm install
npm WARN deprecated jade@1.11.0: Jade has been renamed to pug, please install the latest version of pug instead of jade
npm WARN deprecated transformers@2.1.0: Deprecated, use jstransformer
npm WARN deprecated tough-cookie@2.2.2: ReDoS vulnerability parsing Set-Cookie https://nodesecurity.io/advisories/130

bufferutil@1.2.1 install C:\Users\Antonio\Documents\GitHub\IoTWebAPP>\IoTWebDemo\node_modules\bufferutil
node-gyp rebuild


C:\Users\Antonio\Documents\GitHub\IoTWebAPP\IoTWebDemo\node_modules\bufferutil>if not defined npm_config_node_gyp (node "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )  else (node "" rebuild )
Die Projekte in dieser Projektmappe werden nacheinander erstellt. Um eine parallele Erstellung zu ermöglichen, müssen Sie den Schalter "/m" hinzufügen.
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V140\Platforms\x64\PlatformToolsets\v140\Toolset.targets(36,5): error
 MSB8036: The Windows SDK version 8.1 was not found. Install the required version of Windows SDK or change the SDK vers
ion in the project property pages or by right-clicking the solution and selecting "Retarget solution". [C:\Users\Antoni
o\Documents\GitHub\IoTWebAPP\IoTWebDemo\node_modules\bufferutil\build\bufferutil.vcxproj]
gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `msbuild` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:276:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:204:12)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.10586
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\Antonio\Documents\GitHub\IoTWebAPP\IoTWebDemo\node_modules\bufferutil
gyp ERR! node -v v6.3.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.3.1
gyp ERR! not ok
npm WARN install:bufferutil@1.2.1 bufferutil@1.2.1 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm WARN install:bufferutil@1.2.1 Exit status 1

utf-8-validate@1.2.1 install C:\Users\Antonio\Documents\GitHub\IoTWebAPP\IoTWebDemo\node_modules\utf-8-validate
node-gyp rebuild


C:\Users\Antonio\Documents\GitHub\IoTWebAPP\IoTWebDemo\node_modules\utf-8-validate>if not defined npm_config_node_gyp (node "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )  else (node "" rebuild )
Die Projekte in dieser Projektmappe werden nacheinander erstellt. Um eine parallele Erstellung zu ermöglichen, müssen Sie den Schalter "/m" hinzufügen.
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V140\Platforms\x64\PlatformToolsets\v140\Toolset.targets(36,5): error
 MSB8036: The Windows SDK version 8.1 was not found. Install the required version of Windows SDK or change the SDK vers
ion in the project property pages or by right-clicking the solution and selecting "Retarget solution". [C:\Users\Antoni
o\Documents\GitHub\IoTWebAPP\IoTWebDemo\node_modules\utf-8-validate\build\validation.vcxproj]

gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `msbuild` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (C:\Program Files\nodejs

\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:276:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:204:12)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.10586
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\Antonio\Documents\GitHub\IoTWebAPP\IoTWebDemo\node_modules\utf-8-validate
gyp ERR! node -v v6.3.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.3.1
gyp ERR! not ok
npm WARN install:utf-8-validate@1.2.1 utf-8-validate@1.2.1 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm WARN install:utf-8-validate@1.2.1 Exit status 1
aws@0.0.0 C:\Users\Antonio\Documents\GitHub\IoTWebAPP\IoTWebDemo
+-- body-parser@1.13.3
| +-- bytes@2.1.0
| +-- content-type@1.0.2
| +-- depd@1.0.1
| +-- http-errors@1.3.1
| | +-- inherits@2.0.1
| | `-- statuses@1.3.0
| +-- iconv-lite@0.4.11
| +-- on-finished@2.3.0
| | `-- ee-first@1.1.1
.
.
.
  +-- has-binary-data@0.1.3
  | `-- isarray@0.0.1
  +-- socket.io-adapter@0.3.1
  | +-- debug@1.0.2
  | | `-- ms@0.6.2
  | +-- object-keys@1.0.1
  | `-- socket.io-parser@2.2.2
  |   +-- debug@0.7.4
  |   `-- isarray@0.0.1
  +-- socket.io-client@1.3.7
  | +-- backo2@1.0.2
  | +-- component-bind@1.0.0
  | +-- component-emitter@1.1.2
  | +-- debug@0.7.4
  | +-- engine.io-client@1.5.4
  | | +-- component-inherit@0.0.3
  | | +-- debug@1.0.4
  | | | `-- ms@0.6.2
  | | +-- has-cors@1.0.3
  | | | `-- global@2.0.1
  | | +-- parsejson@0.0.1
  | | +-- parseqs@0.0.2
  | | +-- parseuri@0.0.4
  | | `-- xmlhttprequest@1.5.0
  | +-- has-binary@0.1.6
  | | `-- isarray@0.0.1
  | +-- indexof@0.0.1
  | +-- object-component@0.0.3
  | +-- parseuri@0.0.2
  | | `-- better-assert@1.0.2
  | |   `-- callsite@1.0.0
  | `-- to-array@0.1.3
  `-- socket.io-parser@2.2.4
    +-- benchmark@1.0.0
    +-- debug@0.7.4
    +-- isarray@0.0.1
    `-- json3@3.2.6
C:\Users\Antonio\Documents\GitHub\IoTWebAPP\IoTWebDemo [master ≡ +1 ~1 -0 !]>
```

after "npm start" and starting webapp at localhost

```
C:\Users\Antonio\Documents\GitHub\IoTWebAPP\IoTWebDemo [master ≡ +2 ~1 -0 !]> npm start

aws@0.0.0 start C:\Users\Antonio\Documents\GitHub\IoTWebAPP\IoTWebDemo
node ./bin/www

a user connected
C:\Users\Antonio\Documents\GitHub\IoTWebAPP\IoTWebDemo\app.js:48
                        humidity_data = body.msg.humidity
                                                ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'humidity' of undefined
    at Request._callback (C:\Users\Antonio\Documents\GitHub\IoTWebAPP\IoTWebDemo\app.js:48:28)
    at Request.self.callback (C:\Users\Antonio\Documents\GitHub\IoTWebAPP\IoTWebDemo\node_modules\request\request.js:198:22)
    at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
    at Request.emit (events.js:191:7)
    at Request.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Antonio\Documents\GitHub\IoTWebAPP\IoTWebDemo\node_modules\request\request.js:1082:10)
    at emitOne (events.js:101:20)
    at Request.emit (events.js:188:7)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Antonio\Documents\GitHub\IoTWebAPP\IoTWebDemo\node_modules\request\request.js:1009:12)
    at emitNone (events.js:91:20)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:185:7)

npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.10586
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "start"
npm ERR! node v6.3.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.3
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! aws@0.0.0 start: `node ./bin/www`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the aws@0.0.0 start script 'node ./bin/www'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the aws package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node ./bin/www
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs aws
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls aws
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Antonio\Documents\GitHub\IoTWebAPP\IoTWebDemo\npm-debug.log
C:\Users\Antonio\Documents\GitHub\IoTWebAPP\IoTWebDemo [master ≡ +2 ~1 -0 !]>
```

here the app.js file:

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var routes = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');

var app = express();
var request = require('request');
/* url  */
var humidity_url = "https://iot.seeed.cc/v1/node/GroveTempHumD0/humidity?access_token=xxx";

var temperature_url = "https://iot.seeed.cc/v1/node/GroveTempHumD0/temperature?access_token=xxx";

var light_url = "https://iot.seeed.cc/v1/node/GenericAInA0/analog?access_token=xxx";

var moisture_url = "https://iot.seeed.cc/v1/node/GroveBaroBMP085I2C0/pressure?access_token=xxx";

var quality_url = "https://iot.seeed.cc/v1/node/GroveBaroBMP085I2C0/altitude?access_token=xxx";

//var humidity_url = "https://120.25.216.117/v1/node/GroveTempHum/humidity?access_token=6b53bce4b8c63c886f4449efa782e232";

//var temperature_url = "https://120.25.216.117/v1/node/GroveTempHum/temperature?access_token=6b53bce4b8c63c886f4449efa782e232";

//var light_url = "https://120.25.216.117/v1/node/GroveDigitalLight/lux?access_token=6b53bce4b8c63c886f4449efa782e232";

//var moisture_url = "https://cn.iot.seeed.cc/v1/node/GroveMoisture/moisture?access_token=bf162002b220b9d45028bb0053b4a17f";

//var quality_url = "https://120.25.216.117/v1/node/GroveAirquality/quality?access_token=6b53bce4b8c63c886f4449efa782e232";

app.io = require('socket.io')();

app.io.on('connection', function(socket){
    console.log('a user connected');
    var humidity_data ;
    update_humidity_data = function(){
        request({method: 'GET',
                url:humidity_url,
                json: true,
                strictSSL: false, 
                rejectUnhauthorized : false 
                }, function (error, response, body) {
      if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
         //var info = JSON.parse(body)
            humidity_data = body.msg.humidity
         console.log(body.msg.humidity)
         socket.emit('humidity_data',humidity_data);
         //console.log(info)
      }else
          console.log(error)
     })
    }

    update_temperature_data = function(){
        request({method: 'GET',
                url:temperature_url,
                json: true,
                strictSSL: false, 
                rejectUnhauthorized : false 
                }, function (error, response, body) {
      if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
         //var info = JSON.parse(body)
            temperature_data = body.msg.temperature
         console.log(body.msg.temperature)
         socket.emit('temperature_data',temperature_data);
         //console.log(info)
      }else
          console.log(error)
     })
    }

    update_moisture_data = function(){
        request({method: 'GET',
                url:moisture_url,
                json: true,
                strictSSL: false, 
                rejectUnhauthorized : false 
                }, function (error, response, body) {
      if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
         //var info = JSON.parse(body)
            moisture_data = body.msg.moisture;
         console.log(body.msg.moisture);
         socket.emit('moisture_data',moisture_data);
         //console.log(info)
      }else
          console.log(error)
     })
    }

    update_light_data = function(){
        request({method: 'GET',
                url:light_url,
                json: true,
                strictSSL: false, 
                rejectUnhauthorized : false 
                }, function (error, response, body) {
      if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
         //var info = JSON.parse(body)
            light_data = body.msg.lux;
         console.log(body.msg.lux)
         socket.emit('light_data',light_data);
         //console.log(info)
      }else
          console.log(error)
     })
    }

    update_quality_data = function(){
        request({method: 'GET',
                url:quality_url,
                json: true,
                strictSSL: false, 
                rejectUnhauthorized : false 
                }, function (error, response, body) {
      if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
         //var info = JSON.parse(body)
            quality_data = body.msg.quality;
         console.log(body.msg.temperature);
         socket.emit('quality_data',quality_data);
         //console.log(info)
      }else
          console.log(error)
     })
    }

    update_date =function(){
        update_humidity_data();
        update_temperature_data();
        update_light_data();
        update_moisture_data();
        update_quality_data();
    }

    setInterval(update_date,2000);
    // setInterval(update_humidity_data,1000);
    // setInterval(update_temperature_data,1500);
    // setInterval(update_moisture_data,1000);
    // setInterval(update_light_data,2000);
    // setInterval(update_quality_data,2500);
  socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
    console.log('message: ' + msg);
  }); 
});

var ejs=require('ejs');//新增  
//添加以下  
app.engine('.html',ejs.__express);  
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'html');  




// view engine setup

//app.set('view engine', 'jade');

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', routes);
app.use('/users', users);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});

// error handlers

// development error handler
// will print stacktrace
if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
  app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.render('error', {
      message: err.message,
      error: err
    });
  });
}

// production error handler
// no stacktraces leaked to user
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error', {
    message: err.message,
    error: {}
  });
});


module.exports = app;
```

any suggestion?

Thanks

Comment: No `msg` property on `body` object? Can you post app.js? Or at least the relevant parts, like how you're initializing `body`? Also, something showing what the request you're sending to the app looks like may be helpful.

Comment: What does `console.dir(body)` output right inside your `request()` callback in `update_humidity_data()`? What is in `response.headers`? Perhaps `response.headers['content-type'] !== 'application/json'`?

Comment: This is pretty straightforward—there's no `msg` field on `body`.

Comment: Also, look at `npm install` logs: 
`The Windows SDK version 8.1 was not found. Install the required version of Windows SDK or change the SDK vers
ion in the project property pages or by right-clicking the solution and selecting "Retarget solution".`

Comment: @mscdex: the body content is: { humidity: 47 }
how I can extract the value from json? I receive this error: C:\Users\Antonio\Documents\GitHub\IoTWebAPP\IoTWebDemo\app.js:52
                 humidity_data = body.msg.humidity;
                                         ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'humidity' of undefined

Comment: @james_womack: why I don't have a msg field in body?

Comment: @oxid2178 I assume because the HTTP service you're talking to isn't returning a JSON payload with `msg` in it. `console.dir` out the result you're getting (`body`) and you'll know what's up.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [API documentation](http://seeed-studio.github.io/Wio_Link/#read-the-property-of-a-grove-module) there is no `msg` property on the result returned from the API server. The requested values are attached directly to the object returned (e.g. `{ temp: 30 }`).

Comment: Now it works well. I changed in "humidity_data = body.humidity;" and "temperature_data = body.celsius_degree;". Thanks you all...